# Run rake on multiple environments

Tags: ruby, rake

I know `rake db:migrate` changes the *development* database, and I can `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` to change the *test* database.

How can I execute the same task on both environments with a single command?

Answer (score 1):

How about this command:

```
rake db:migrate && RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Actually, I thought that migrating your test database shouldn't usually be needed because Rails has some feature for automatically copying the structure of your dev database over to it.